# How can I use a timer to delay a specific task not associated with the timer class (java.util.timer)?

Tags: java

I am making a text-based RPG for a personal project in Java. In the game the protagonist will have at his/her disposal the ability to use a spell or ability. I would like to add a cool down to the aforementioned spell or ability. I have researched both the javax.swing.Timer and java.util.Timer classes but have not found a way to go about using this cool down. I am not using threads or daemons (primarily because I don't think I need to and I have zero experience with them).

Any help or ideas on how to go about this would be appreciated, thanks.

- Alumnus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just save System.currentTimeMillis() at the time the spell is cast and check the time elapsed when the hero tries to cast it again.

Answer (score 0):

When you use your spell, set some variable to say that the spell is now unavailable. Then start a timer that will act as your cool down. When the timer ticks, reset that variable to indicate that it has cooled down and can be used again.

Answer (score 0):

If possible you could save the current game time when the spell/ability gets triggered inside your application and disable the ability.
Then again if yo can do it you can check every "frame update" if the cool down time has already elapsed by computing the time difference between the current time and the time the spell/ability got triggered and reenable the ability when the desired time has elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

If this RPG is turn based combat then do this:

Make a cooldown variable with the number of turns needed to wait for cooldown.

Now make another variable for current cooldown turn, now set its value to the same as the cooldown like
`curcooldown = waitforcooldown`, something like that.

And then if you check that the player wants to use the spell and then check it like this.

```
If player wants to use spell & curcooldown is 0
    UseSpell
Else if (player wants to use spell & curcooldown greater or equal to 0
    saytoplayerthatspellisundercooldown
```

and if spell is used then `curcooldown = waitforcooldown`
set it to the cooldown value turn value.
and every time a turn ends then decrease the curcooldownvalue by 1 that means your cooldown just lost 1 turn and so on...

Hope this helped